# Pod::Usage: `=begin :text`/`=end :text` messes up formatting

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I have some POD documentation with a section that should be rendered differently in Latex (using `pod2latex`) and plain text/man.  For this purpose, I have a `=begin :text`/`=end :text` section.

Now, I want to show individual sections of the POD on the command line (using `Pod::Usage`).  And this is where the problem comes in: All the sections *after* the `:text` block come out garbled in this mode.

Here's a minimal example:

```
pod2usage(-verbose => 99, -sections => 'Two');

=head1 One

=begin text

For I<non-Latex> only.

=end text

=head1 Two

C<Formatting> all I<messed> up!
```

Output:

```
Two:
"Formatting"*messed*     all up!
```

Note that printing the whole POD (`pod2usage(-verbose => 2);` or just running `perldoc` on the file) works fine.

I have tried all the `Pod::Usage` options that I could find (including selecting a different *Formatter* class), but to now avail.  If I remove the `:text` from the block (plain `=begin`/`=end`), it comes out all right with the section selection, but this is actually a POD syntax error, and `perldoc` complains about it when rendering the whole POD.

NB: My Perl is quite old (v5.18.2), but I am stuck with that version.

Comment: I can confirm, and no tweaking helped (adding text before/after the =begin...=end, removing formatting from inside it...). That's very unpleasant and I don't see how to circumvent it at all. It looks to me every bit as a bug (in `Pod::Usage`?).

Comment: Tried to figure it out by looking at the source but it is quite complicated. The code even warns you against it :)  see [line 3](https://metacpan.org/release/KHW/Pod-Simple-3.43/source/lib/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm#L3) and [line 802](https://metacpan.org/release/KHW/Pod-Simple-3.43/source/lib/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm#L802)

Comment: Added [bug report](https://github.com/Dual-Life/Pod-Usage/issues/18)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `Pod::Usage`. I found a workaround by looking at the source code. It seems that the internal stack of `Pod::Simple` gets messed up due to a missing sub `cmd_for`. By adding a dummy sub `cmd_for` manually it seems to work:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Pod::Usage;
{
    no warnings 'once';
    *Pod::Usage::cmd_for = sub { };
}

pod2usage(-verbose => 99, -sections => 'Two');

=head1 One

=begin text

For I<non-Latex> only.

=end text

=head1 Two

C<Formatting> all I<messed> up!
```

**Output**:

```
Two:
    "Formatting" all messed up!
```

Comment: Nice! How do you get it to print text under `=begin text ... =end text`?  I remove `-sections` option and change verbose to `2` -- trying to print all documentation -- but the `text` isn't printed?

Comment: @zdim Yes you are right it does not work for all the text. I have updated my answer with another approach.

Comment: Wow, you really went all out, thanks!  The earlier solution also worked for me, sort of, but required an ugly hack to get the `text` section to print where it was needed.  I will try the new approach soon.